# Change the raw string representation of a date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, date, object, prototype

I have a series of Javascript classes that extend the Date object to cover different calendars. The idea is that, regardless of calendar, the Unix timestamp stored by a Date object is universal.

So, I can have `const julianChristmas = new JulianDate(2023, 11, 25)` which encodes Christmas Day in the Julian calendar. I've set the various string methods to return nice representations of the date, but if I do `console.log(julianChristmas)`, I still get a string with the equivalent Gregorian date for 7 Jan 2024.

Is there anyway to overwrite the default behaviour of Date in JulianDate (and the other classes) so that it won't display Gregorian date representations?

I've rewritten all of the documented string methods of Date in the class, but none of them overwrites the default representation.

Comment: The timestamp stored by a Date object is *already* universal.

Comment: Perhaps look into the [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) facility. Of course, you can also use the various Date APIs to get the "pieces" of a date/time value and arrange those in a string however you want.

Comment: Forcing an object into a string context (like that console.log statement does), looks for a method named `toString` - and if that exists, it will get invoked, to _get_ the string representation of the object. So you'd have to provide `JulianDate` with your own `toString` method, to overwrite the default it inherited from `Date`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Comment: As for your subclassed date implementations, each class needs to feature its own `toString` method. The latter is responsible for how any instance of your date classes gets presented when an implicit *to string* (like with a `conbsole.log`) happens to it.

Comment: @CBroe the console doesn't *necessarily* convert the object to a string. Browser console would print the object *as well as* the date it represents. Even if the object is converted to a string, that's not necessarily by `toString()` - in Node would (by necessity) use [`@@util.inspect.custom`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectcustom). The correct thing is to *not* try and make the object "automatically" behave somehow in console but *explicitly* make it behave differently. A polymorphic `.formatMe()` (rename as appropriate) method or even an external formatter.

Comment: @VLAZ I assume that if the class doesn't have that method it falls back on `toString()`. So if the `DateTime` class has no custom inspector, you only need to override `toString()` to get what's wanted.